# Clojure returning simple true or false from a function

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure and i am having trouble with the basics of it. I am trying to write a simple if else program and use it in recursion but i am having trouble with the syntax. The code in Java is :

```
if(a > 0 && b >0){
   return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
```

The code in clojure should be :

```
(defn checkPositiveNumber 
    [x y]
    (if (and (> x 0) (> y 0))
            (do 
                (def val true)
            )
            (do 
                (def val false) 
    )
)

(println (checkPositiveNumber 2 3))
```

returns `#'user/val` instead of false.
What am i doing wrong ? This function should return true or false as i will be using it to either terminate my recursion or to check further.

Edit:
Thanks to Lee i was able to achieve the thing i asked... But my real purpose is :

```
if(a > 0 && b >0){
       System.out.println("Values are Positive");
       return true;
    }else{
      System.out.println("Some Values are Negative");
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your Java did not compile: `and` is not an operator. I think you intend the `&&` operator, and have edited your question accordingly.

Comment: that was more of pseudo code for the reference of what i want to achieve in Java . Wrote to much of clojure code, mixed the syntax of Java.Thanks anyways..

Comment: ... and, as with Clojure, your original Java could be shortened to `return a > 0 && b > 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no analogue of `return` in clojure. Clojure function bodies are expressions so you need to organise your function to evaluate to `true` or `false` for each case.

In this case you don't need to use `if` at all:

```
(defn checkPositiveNumber [x y]
  (and (> x 0) (> y 0)))
```

if you want to execute some side-effect in each branch you can use `do`:

```
(defn checkPositiveNumber [x y]
   (if (and (> x 0) (> y 0)))
     (do
       (println "x and y both positive")
       true)
     (do
       (println "One of x or y non-positive")
       false)))
```

Comment: But what if i need to write java equivalent code of : if(a > 0 and b >0){
   sout("all values are positive");return true;
}else{
  sout("there is a negative value");return false;
}

Comment: @heman123 - Then you'd use an `if` and a `do` in each branch.

Comment: But after printing the statement i want to return true and false. How to achieve that ? i am still not understanding. I will edit my question according to that.. can you please  suggest corresponding edit

Comment: Thanks alot @Lee .. I was able to do it as you said... Is clojure really tough or is it just me who is finding it difficult ?

Comment: @heman123 - Clojure is fairly different to java and might take some time getting used to but I think learning a functional language will improve how you write in other langauges (including java) too.

Answer (score 3):

To further Lee's answer, you could also make use of the `every?` function to make your function more general:

```
(defn every-pos? [& values]
  (every? pos? values))
```

This function has the advantage in that you don't have to specify the evaluation of each argument and it takes an unlimited number of parameters:

```
=> (every-pos? 1 7)
true
=> (every-pos? 3 -1 13 2)
false
```

Learning to metaprogram with sequences rather than individual values really demonstrates the strengths of functional programming.

To check the value and include side-effects, something like the following would do the job:

```
(defn check-positive-numbers [x y]
  (let [pos-values? (every-pos? x y)
        msg (if pos-values?
              "all numbers positive" 
              "one or more numbers non-positive")]
    (println msg)
    pos-values?))
```